# KeywordQuery: Seach Multiple Content Types

Tags: 2013, search, keywordquery

Is it possible to search multiple content types with KeywordQuery?

```
ContentTypeName: Content Type A AND ContentTypeName: Content Type B
```

Comment: Also, if you use ContentTypeId you can retrieve parent and children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is. Use the following query:

```
{{searchterms} (ContentType:A) AND (ContentType:B)}
```

I would personally use `SPContentType:`